# Oracle Sql : Displaying result when row value is associated with another row?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I got a table as below ,

```
INV_CODE  INV_NO     INV_STATUS   INV-DATE    INV-REF-CODE     INV_REF_NO    
 DN       202001        3          02/01/20        SO             202002                    
 DN       202002        1          03/01/20        SO             202001                        
 INV      202001        0          03/01/20        DN             202002          
 INV      202002        2          04/01/20        DN             202001          
 DN       202003        1          05/01/20        SO            202005
```

Here we got INV_CODE and INV-REF-COD as  SO,DN,INV

fetch only SO  which has DN and that DN got an INV entry in the table

I want to display result like follows

```
INV-REF-CODE   INV_REF_NO   INV_CODE     INV_NO    INV_REF_CODE2    INV_REF_NO 2
 SO             202001        INV        202001       DN          202002
 SO             202002        INV        202002       DN          202001
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-join; this seems to be the result you want:

```
select t2.INV_REF_CODE, t1.INV_REF_NO, t1.INV_CODE, t2.INV_NO,
  t1.INV_REF_CODE as INV_REF_CODE_2, t1.INV_NO as INV_REF_NO_2
from your_table t1
join your_table t2 on t2.INV_NO = t1.INV_REF_NO
and t2.INV_CODE = 'DN'
where t1.INV_CODE = 'INV';
```

```
INV_REF_CODE | INV_REF_NO | INV_CODE | INV_NO | INV_REF_CODE_2 | INV_REF_NO_2
:----------- | ---------: | :------- | -----: | :------------- | -----------:
SO           |     202001 | INV      | 202001 | DN             |       202002
SO           |     202002 | INV      | 202002 | DN             |       202001
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=85747b72e370da6c893f7ec6ef98ec05)

Comment: can u also add date range in the where clause , ie we want only  result between two dates?

Comment: like inv date between 02 and 04

Comment: Well, with actual dates, e.g.: `and t1.inv_date >= date '2020-01-02' and t1.inv_date < date '2020-01-05'`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bb24e8398d81f39070439a77d882a61a)

Comment: can u add them in ur result